How can I interlock doors to a bathroom
To electronically lock doors, I have used an electric strike for timber doors (where part of the strike hinges open) or a V-Bolt for aluminium doors (where the bolt goes inside the frame of the door.
In the new house that we are building, we have 2 Jack-and-Jill bathrooms.  Bathrooms that have 2 doors.  It is always embarrassing when someone forgets to lock both doors.
I was thinking of some lock that I could install in cavity sliders.  I could then use the home automation to lock the other door, when one door is locked and conversely, unlock the other door when a door is unlocked.
I haven't found small electronic locks for sliding doors, yet.  I am still looking. This is not about looking for locks  I will find them.
How can I achieve this task?  I am open to any solution.

that's  not really an IoT question

It seems that any smart lock can be told to lock/unlock, right? Build an automation that triggers on "lock status change" of Lock A and ensures Lock B stay in sync and vice-versa. Seems reasonably straightforward...

ask about pocket door locks at https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions

how about a red/green indicator that shows if the bathroom light is on? ... or if one of the doors is locked?

@jsotola, why do you think its not an automation question, when the solution requires automation.

@RohitGupta your question appears to be about the locks themselves

@jsotola, I  though i made it clear that i was looking for locks atm, but was open to other solutions.

You can consider asking in DIY SE instead. Right now you can't delete this question because you've posted an answer. If you delete your answer, you can then delete the question and post it there instead. Alternatively you could flag for moderation assistance and ask to have it migrated there.

@jsotola's comment has given me the answer.
I will install push buttons with leds on both exits. The home automation will lock/ unlock both doors.
